# From coin flips to algebraic functions via pushdown automata

Tags: pr.probability

#### Background

We're given a coin that shows heads with an unknown probability, $\lambda$. The goal is to use that coin (and possibly also a fair coin) to build a "new" coin that shows heads with a probability that depends on $\lambda$, call it $f(\lambda)$. This is the *Bernoulli factory problem*, and it can be solved only for certain functions $f$. (For example, flipping the coin twice and taking heads only if exactly one coin shows heads, we can simulate the probability $2\lambda(1-\lambda)$.)

Specifically, the only functions that can be simulated this way **are continuous and polynomially bounded on their domain, and map $[0, 1]$ or a subset thereof to $[0, 1]$**, as well as $f=0$ and $f=1$. These functions are called *factory functions* in this question. (A function $f(x)$ is *polynomially bounded* if both $f$ and $1-f$ are bounded below by min($x^n$, $(1-x)^n$) for some integer $n$ (Keane and O'Brien 1994). This implies that $f$ admits no roots on (0, 1) and can't take on the value 0 or 1 except possibly at 0 and/or 1.)

This is one of my [open questions on the Bernoulli factory problem](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernreq.html); see the linked page for others.

This question is about solving the Bernoulli factory problem on a restricted computing model, namely the model of *pushdown automata* (finite-state machines with a stack) that are driven by flips of a coin and produce new probabilities.

### Main Question

A function $f(\lambda)$ is *algebraic over the rational numbers* if there is a nonzero polynomial $P(x, y)$ in two variables and whose coefficients are rational numbers, such that $P(x, f(x)) = 0$ for every $x$ in the domain of $f$.

Given that $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is continuous and polynomially bounded, is $f$ algebraic over the rational numbers only if it can be simulated by a pushdown automaton, defined below?  If not, which functions algebraic over the rational numbers can be so simulated?

In particular, can the following functions be simulated this way?

- min($\lambda$, $1-\lambda$).
- $\lambda^{1/p}$ for prime $p\ge 3$.

#### Pushdown Automata

A *pushdown automaton* has a finite set of *states* and a finite set of *stack symbols*, one of which is called EMPTY and takes a biased coin with an unknown probability of heads. It starts with a given state and its stack starts with EMPTY. On each iteration:

- The automaton flips the coin.
- Based on the coin flip (HEADS or TAILS), the current state, and the top stack symbol, it moves to a new state (or keeps it unchanged) and replaces the top stack symbol with zero, one, or two symbols. Thus, there are three kinds of *transition rules*:

  - (*state*, *flip*, *symbol*) → (*state2*, {*symbol2*}): move to *state2*, replace top stack symbol with same or different one.
  - (*state*, *flip*, *symbol*) → (*state2*, {*symbol2*, *new*}): move to *state2*, replace top stack symbol with *symbol2*, then *push* a new symbol (*new*) onto the stack.
  - (*state*, *flip*, *symbol*) → (*state2*, {}): move to *state2*, *pop* the top symbol from the stack.

When the stack is empty, the machine stops and returns either 0 or 1 depending on the state it ends up at. (For the questions below, let *flip* be HEADS, TAILS, or a rational number in [0, 1]; this likewise reduces to the definition above.  The rest of this question assumes the pushdown automaton terminates with probability 1.)

#### Algebraic Functions

Let $f: (0, 1) \to (0, 1)$ be continuous.  Mossel and Peres (2005) showed that a pushdown automaton can simulate $f$ only if $f$ is *algebraic over the rational numbers*.  The algebraic function generated by pushdown automata corresponds to a system of polynomial equations, as described by Mossel and Peres (2005) and Esparza et al. 2004.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the class of continuous functions that map (0, 1) to (0, 1) and are algebraic over rationals.  The constants 0 and 1 are also in $\mathcal{C}$.

Let $\mathcal{D} \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ be the class of functions that a pushdown automaton can simulate.

I don't yet know whether $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{C}$ (and that was also a question of Mossel and Peres).

The following section of my open-source page, https://peteroupc.github.io/morealg.html#Pushdown_Automata_and_Algebraic_Functions, contains information on the question. As that section shows, I could establish the following about the class $\mathcal{D}$:

- $\sqrt{\lambda}$ is in $\mathcal{D}$, and so is every rational function in $\mathcal{C}$.
- If $f(\lambda)$ and $g(\lambda)$ are in $\mathcal{D}$, then so are their product and composition.
- If $f(\lambda)$ is in $\mathcal{D}$, then so is every Bernstein-form polynomial in the variable $f(\lambda)$ with coefficients in $\mathcal{D}$.
- If a pushdown automaton can generate a discrete distribution of *n*-letter words, then that distribution's probability generating function is in $\mathcal{D}$ (cf. Dughmi et al. 2021).
- If a pushdown automaton can generate a discrete distribution of *n*-letter words of the same letter, it can generate that distribution conditioned on a finite set of word lengths, or a periodic infinite set of word lengths (e.g., odd word lengths only).
- Every quadratic irrational in (0, 1) is in $\mathcal{D}$.

I suspect that the answer to the main question is no, not all functions algebraic over rational numbers can be simulated by a pushdown automaton.  The following are remarks on this question:

- Etessami and Yannakakis (2009) showed that pushdown automata with rational probabilities are equivalent to recursive Markov chains (with rational transition probabilities), and that for every recursive Markov chain, the system of polynomial equations has nonnegative coefficients. But this paper doesn't deal with the case of recursive Markov chains where the transition probabilities cannot just be rational, but can also be $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an unknown rational or irrational probability of heads.
- Banderier and Drmota (2014) showed the asymptotic behavior of power series solutions $f(\lambda)$ of a polynomial system, where both the series and the system have nonnegative real coefficients. Notably, functions of the form $\lambda^{1/p}$ where $p\ge 3$ is not a power of 2, are not possible solutions, because their so-called "critical exponent" is not dyadic. But the result seems not to apply to *piecewise* power series such as $\min(\lambda,1-\lambda)$, which are likewise algebraic functions.

### References

- Keane, M. S., and O'Brien, G. L., "A Bernoulli factory", ACM Transactions on Modeling and Computer Simulation 4(2), 1994.
- Mossel, Elchanan, and Yuval Peres. New coins from old: computing with unknown bias. Combinatorica, 25(6), pp.707-724, 2005.
- Icard, Thomas F., "Calibrating generative models: The probabilistic Chomsky–Schützenberger hierarchy." Journal of Mathematical Psychology 95 (2020): 102308.
- Dughmi, Shaddin, Jason Hartline, Robert D. Kleinberg, and Rad Niazadeh. "Bernoulli Factories and Black-box Reductions in Mechanism Design." Journal of the ACM (JACM) 68, no. 2 (2021): 1-30.
- Etessami, K. And Yannakakis, M., "Recursive Markov chains, stochastic grammars, and monotone systems of nonlinear equations", Journal of the ACM 56(1), pp.1-66, 2009.
- Banderier, C. And Drmota, M., 2015. Formulae and asymptotics for coefficients of algebraic functions. Combinatorics, Probability and Computing, 24(1), pp.1-53.
- Esparza, J., Kučera, A. and Mayr, R., 2004, July. Model checking probabilistic pushdown automata. In Proceedings of the 19th Annual IEEE Symposium on Logic in Computer Science, 2004. (pp. 12-21). IEEE.